# How do I delete a tag in Hamster Time Tracking?

Tags: hamster

Is there a possibility to delete a tag in [Hamster Time Tracking](http://projecthamster.org/)?

I went through all graphical menus but couldn't find any option.

The closest one is the following but it doesn't list my own tags:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question so we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the database file of hamster in `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db` to delete tags.

#### CLI method

We'll use `sqlite3` program to do editing from command line.

1. Install it using this command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sqlite3
   ```
2. Then open the database file

   ```
   sqlite3 ~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db
   ```
3. See all the tags defined (Optional)

   ```
   select * from tags;
   ```

   This may return something like this.

   ```
   3|au|true
   ```

   Here, The first column is ID, second one is name and third one controls whether or not this tag should be shown for autocompletion.
4. Now, To remove a tag named `au` (for example)

   ```
   delete from tags where name = 'au';
   ```

   This will delete the tag with `au` name. You can check using `select * from tags;`.
5. Now, save the database (otherwise the save will not persist)

   ```
   .save ~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db
   ```
6. Quit the sqlite3 prompt using command

   ```
   .quit;
   ```

#### Graphical method

1. Install any sqlite3 database editor. Such as `sqliteman`.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install sqliteman
   ```
2. Open the database file in `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db`.
3. Navigate to **Schema** tab, **main** -> **Tables**. Double click **tags** to see it's data on the right-hand side panel.
4. Select the row for the tab you want to remove and click on **Remove Row** button above.
5. Then click on **Commit Current Transaction** to save the changes.
6. Exit Sqliteman.

Here is a simple screenshot indicating the buttons in SQLiteman

[image: sqliteman buttons, which is which]

---

Thanks to SteveK's hint on Editing the database file.

Comment: @orschiro Glad that it helped :) Thank you too! Because I wasn't expecting an accept considering the age of the question.

Comment: I always aspire to follow-up and have genuine conversations. :-) You might want to add a screenshot of the graphical interface.

Comment: @orschiro There you go!

Comment: This is fantastic! :-)

Comment: Another thing is I could see the tags listed below in Xfce. Though there was no way to delete. May be it was Unity's problem to show the tags

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the same, since I want to get rid of some the suggested tags.

To me it seems like that all the tags are stored in the database file: `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db`. I tried to edit this file by deleting tags, but without success. The problem is that there are a number of additional characters around the tag you might or might not have to delete but to me it is not clear where to start and stop deleting.

After editing the file hamster did not respond and the only solution to this is to restore the file. So better make a backup before trying yourself (`cp ~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db ~/.local/share/hamster-applet/hamster.db.bak`)